# I need a synonym for "transfer" which makes clear that the recipient has initiated the transfer

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I have following situation: There is a software system for managing to-do lists for a team. If a team member sees that a coworker has too much on his list, she can decide to transfer the feature to her own list in order to help him. But if I just say "The software allows users to transfer todos between lists", it sounds like they are able to push their own tasks to other's lists. I need a word for "transfer", which makes clear that the new task owner has initiated the transfer, so it sounds nice. A long explanation won't do, as it is bad for marketing, it should be a single verb. Something like "take over", but "take over" doesn't feel right to me - or is it OK?

Comment: Like "adopt" or "take ownership" ?

Comment: I liked "adopt" best, because it has an altruistic ring to it. Will you pleas make it a full answer?

Comment: here you are;  I've now upgraded my comment to a full-fledged answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context that you describe, I believe you could possibly use "adopt".

It conveys two desirable meanings:

- Adoptions are one way transfers left at the initiative of would-be adopters.
- Adopters actively take responsibility for their adopted to-do list item.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider "capture" or "assume" or "acquire" to mean "take over" something.

Comment: I like the "assume" option. Something like "assume repsonsibility" or "assume control."

Comment: Or "assume ownership" of something.

Comment: While assume has exactly the meaning I was looking for, its additional meanings are not as positive (like "seize", "usurp"). I'd use it in a generic text without a second thought, but it is not my first choice for marketing material. Still, the suggestions were very good.

Answer (score 2):

I like "assume." You might also consider "undertake" or "appropriate."

Answer (score 1):

How about

> The software allows users to **move** todos to their own list"

No connotations, represents what you said exactly (the pragmatics of who does what to whom, I think), all you have to do now is worry about singular 'they'.